# jQuery $.post() and PHP issue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

It's not updating and I'm missing what I'm doing wrong.  Uses HTML, jQuery, and PHP.  All code is posted below.

What I'm trying to do is allow a user to change a 'client' seed and when it' changed it's updated.  In the  it's displayed.  All that does is refresh every 100ms from a file that's echoing it out.  There's no issue there.

PHP Code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once('db.php');

if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
    switch($_POST['action']) {

        case 'get_client':
            echo json_encode(array('result' =>  $_SESSION['client']));
        break;

        case 'modify_client':
            if(isset($_POST['client']) && strlen($_POST['client']) == 6 && is_numeric($_POST['client']))  {
                $_SESSION['client'] = $_POST['client'];
                echo json_encode(array('result' => true));

              $secret = 123;
                    $_SESSION['server'] = hash('sha512', $_SESSION['roll'] . $_SESSION['client'] . $secret );
            }

            else {
                echo json_encode(array('result' => false));
            }
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $.post('./php/show_client.php', { action: 'get_client' }, function(result) {
            var result = JSON.parse(result);
        })
    });
    $("#client_seed_modify").on("click", function() {
        $.post('./php/show_client.php', { action: 'modify_client', client: $("#client_seed").val() }, function(result) {
            var result = JSON.parse(result);
            if(result ) {

                if(result.result) {
                    alert('Your Client Seed has been changed.  This has also changed the server seed.  Please note that you have the ability to change your client seed freely, but regardless of whether or not you decide to, it does NOT stay the same every roll.');
                }
            }
        });


</script>
```

HTML:

```
  <a>Current Client Seed: <span class="clientShow" style=""> </span></a>
  <p class="field">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Change your Client Seed" name="client" id="cient_seed" class="client_seed">
  </p>
  <p class="field">
    <input type="submit" value="Change Client Seed" style="width: 360px;" name="client_seed_modify" id="client_seed_modify">
  </p>
```

Comment: Is the JavaScript bit your actual code without typos?

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing server side code and client side code. PHP executes on the server, meaning that any links to resources should be file paths to where the actual files on the server are located. Javascript/JQuery is client side code, meaning that it runs in the user's browser, so any links should be urls not file paths.

Instead of using a local file path on the server like you are now with:

```
$.post('./php/show_client.php' ...
```

Your url passed to `$.post()` should be a URL which accesses that PHP script.

```
$.post('mysite.com/directory/show_client.php' ...
```

Comment: No... That's not the issue.